# upgrade data dir from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8

Tags: mysql

Seems like `mysql_upgrade` is deprecated but how to upgrade the database then?

When starting mysql 8 with datadir from mysql 5.7 the server can not start

```
2023-11-27T22:45:15.292059Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 21537
2023-11-27T22:45:15.304214Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2023-11-27T22:45:15.305149Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-27T22:45:20.980119Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-11-27T22:45:23.620739Z 1 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for performance_schema database. Using default Character set.
2023-11-27T22:45:34.506705Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-013669] [Server] The schema "sys" referenced by routine "create_synonym_db" does not exist. Please clean up any orphan routines before upgrading.
2023-11-27T22:45:34.506815Z 2 [ERROR] [MY-010768] [Server] Error in creating stored program 'sys.create_synonym_db'
2023-11-27T22:45:34.515856Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010022] [Server] Failed to Populate DD tables.
2023-11-27T22:45:34.515937Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-27T22:45:39.118629Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: *Seems like mysql_upgrade is deprecated* Version-dependent. If MySQL version is 8.0.16+ then you'd use the `--upgrade` server option. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-what-is-upgraded.html

Comment: Before upgrading use mysql-shell checkForServerUpgrade utility first and review the results.